# Failed response from **Alamofire** in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, postman, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire class for api calling. Api is working properly in Postman
please check below two screenshots for reference,
[image]
in first image data is passing inside raw body

[image]
in second image data is passing inside Headers field
now i'm using this code to call API

```
//for params i'm sending below parameters
//["phoneNumber":"911234567890", "countryCode" : "91"]

let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "deviceId" : deviceId,
            "osVersion": osVersion,
            "deviceType": deviceType,
            "resolution":resolution,
            "buildNumber":buildNumber]

AF.request(strURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:headers).responseData { (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let data):
                    do {
                        //let asJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
                        let asJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.fragmentsAllowed])

                        // success
                        print(asJSON)
                        let res : NSDictionary = (asJSON as AnyObject) as! NSDictionary
                        successBlock(res)
                    } catch { // error
                        print("decoding error:\n\(error)")
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    failure(error)
                }
            }
```

in all other project above code is working fine for api calling, but here i'm getting below error
{ code = 500; data = ""; message = "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Locale'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Locale part "en;q=1.0" contains invalid characters"; …………………… NamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:125)\n\t... 97 more\n"; status = "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"; timestamp = "01-03-2022 07:55:20"; }
i've try several methods like URLEncoding.default, passing custom header, create custom raw request & passed header inside but nothing works,
AnyOne have solution for this issue?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "i've try several methods like URLEncoding.default, passing custom header, create custom raw request & passed header inside but nothing works": I suggested to see the cURL from Postman and Alamofire to compare if there was a difference. What's the output?

Comment: "Why delete previous questions with comments from SO users? " It's like saying: I don't care about ideas/suggestions/questions you gave previously. Especially if there is no improvement on the question.

Comment: @Larme sry for that, i don't want to disclose url that's why.

Comment: A cURL command is code, it's text. You can hide/obfuscate private values (like url, secrets id, etc.). It's about checking it Alamofire code match Postman one...

Comment: @Larme i've checked cURl & compare with alamofire request, both are same & still getting same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is throwing error related to Local, I think some language is defined and it doesn't accept * for `Accept-Language` header, try sending "en" in the header `Accept-Language`.

Check subtags for language:
http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry :

**Test Code:**

```
func callAPI() {
    
    let params: Parameters = ["phoneNumber":"911234567890", "countryCode" : "91"]
    let headers = [
        "deviceId" : "jdhcbkerfjkr",
        "osVersion": "3.2.3",
        "deviceType": "ANDROID",
        "resolution": "122x122",
        "buildNumber": "3.2.1",
        "Accept-Language": "en"]
    
    AF.request("[Test-URL]",
               method: .post,
               parameters: params,
               encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
               headers: HTTPHeaders.init(headers)).response { response in
        print(String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8)!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer! thanks.